# use_frameworks! for only some pods or swift pods

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods, wbwebviewconsole

I have both `Objective C` and `Swift` Pods in my project.

```
pod 'WBWebViewConsole', '~> 1.0.1' 
use_frameworks! 
pod 'XWebView', '~>0.9.5’ 
pod 'Starscream', '~> 1.1.3'
```

As swift PODs(*XWebView*, *Starscream*) can only be added as frameworks I have to use 
***use_frameworks!***

But this makes all the PODs as framework including Objective-C PODs(*WBWebViewConsole*) as well.

But it causes problem with Objective-C POD but I don't intend to make Objective-C POD as framework.

So is there anyway I can ignore couple of PODs from being converted as framework ?

Thanks.

### Update:

*How to reproduce the problem ?*

The problem is with the POD WBWebViewConsole

Run the [attached project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-yFxDqROZVpLUJEWmNoeFRBeHc/view?usp=sharing) in any iOS 8+ devices that has internet connection as it loads a html doc from google drive.

in the html doc … click General/Info/Warning/Debug/Error Log

[image]

you will some text appearing on the html page whenever u click any of the above buttons….

The library is about capturing the logs that’s generated in html page…

Whenever u click the button apart from showing some text in html page I am writing some log in background.

[image]

Now click on the button **get logs** … and see the logs in Xcode IDE… you will see the all the console logs that’s generated in html

[image]

Get logs-> is a native button super imposed on webview..the library lets us read the console logs from wkwebview 
..

Now in the POD 
u uncomment the following lines

```
use_frameworks!
pod 'PLCrashReporter'
pod 'XWebView', '~> 0.9.5’
```

and do pod install

then paste the following code on top of ViewController

```
import WBWebViewConsole
```

Here is the [project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-yFxDqROZVpQVI1OFJ5MUpTek0/view?pref=2&pli=1) with which has all this uncommented with all the changes required to reproduce the problem

now u run the project on device and click some buttons in html page and click *get logs* you can't see comments that's generated in the html page

To be specific below delegate methods implemented in WBWKWebView are not getting fired.

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(WKNavigationAction *)navigationAction decisionHandler:(void (^)(WKNavigationActionPolicy))decisionHandler
- (void)wb_evaluateJavaScript:(NSString *)javaScriptString completionHandler:(void (^)(NSString *, NSError *))completionHandler
```

But while creating the instance of `WBWKWebView` and loading a URL all the necessary delegates of this class are getting fired.

The above delegates are supposed to fire when a log is written while clicking the button in html page

Comment: Are you aware that `use_frameworks!` will work only with `( >= iOS 8.0)` ?

Comment: Oh I wasn't aware of that but my project support starts from iOS 8 only ..so np

Comment: I tried first with `pod 'WBWebViewConsole', '~> 1.0.1'` only then added `use_frameworks! pod 'XWebView', '~>0.9.5’ ` ... Now I have frameworks and files both. Then you can delete what you don't need files/frameworks.

Comment: I tried this http://johannesluderschmidt.de/cocoapods-swift-does-not-work-with-use_frameworks-fix/3281/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `JSBridge` init, it will add some "UserScripts" to webview, which source is loaded from [NSBundle mainBundle] in previous version. But if it's in a framework, the resource files is in the framework bundle instead of `mainBundle`.

So the fix is in `WBWebViewConsoleDefines`

replace this

```
inline static NSBundle * WBWebBrowserConsoleBundle()
{
return [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath], @"WBWebBrowserConsole.bundle"]];
}
```

with

```
inline static NSBundle * WBWebBrowserConsoleBundle()
{
return [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [NSBundle bundleForClass:[WBWebViewConsole class]], @"WBWebBrowserConsole.bundle"]]; 
}
```

Actually the author has released new version it also has the fix

pod 'WBWebViewConsole', '~> 1.0.2’

1. pod install
2. restart Xcode and clean your project
3. build and run again

Note: Its not possible. if you use_frameworks! everything become dynamic framework.

Answer (score 29):

You can overwrite `use_frameworks!` and install all pods as static except for the ones you choose to be a framework

In the **Podfile** use `use_frameworks!` And at the end of the file add

```
dynamic_frameworks = ['aaa','bbb'] # <- swift libraries names

# Make all the other frameworks into static frameworks by overriding the static_framework? function to return true
pre_install do |installer|
  installer.pod_targets.each do |pod|
    if !dynamic_frameworks.include?(pod.name)
      puts "Overriding the static_framework? method for #{pod.name}"
      def pod.static_framework?;
        true
      end
      def pod.build_type;
        Pod::BuildType.static_library
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: perfect solution. but now `Pod::Target::BuildType` is `Pod::BuildType` in cocoapods 1.9.1

Comment: i still got this error: [!] The 'Pods-CallKitExample' target has transitive dependencies that include statically linked binaries: (/Users/thehe/Desktop/CallKitExample/Pods/Vialer-pjsip-iOS/VialerPJSIP.framework) can u help

Comment: Worked perfectly. Just remember to add use_frameworks! before starting of the podfile

Answer (score 4):

**Based on a member of CocoaPods:**

This won't be possible for the general case, because of transitive dependencies. If Pod A is build dynamically and depends on Pod B that is build statically and the app also depends on Pod B, it is for example impossible to build, because either Pod A will be missing the symbols of Pod B at link time, or you end up with multiple copies of Pod B. There are probably more scenarios which won't work.

However, you should be able to create a plugin to support specific cases like yours.

Comment: Any ideas on why the objective c pod is not working as its supposed to be when its converted to framework ?

Comment: could it be due to broken Header/Library/Framework search paths or anything else ?

Comment: check bridging headers

Answer (score 3):

```
                    source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
                    platform :ios, '8.0'
                    use_frameworks!
                    pod 'WBWebViewConsole', '~> 1.0.1' 
                    pod 'XWebView', '~>0.9.5’ 
                    pod 'Starscream', '~> 1.1.3'
```

there is no need for specifying objective c pod above use_framework!.

Comment: the objective c pod is not working as it is supposed to be when its converted to framework.

Answer (score 3):

I use both, Objective-C and Swift, pods together in my project. You have to use the directive `use_frameworks!` if you have to include pods written in Swift. Using `use_frameworks!` directive with non-Swift pods does not cause problem. Put the directive on the top of pods lists.

Generally the Objective-C pods should work by just using `import ModuleName` in whichever swift file you want to use the framework, but if it doesn't then you should try adding **bridging-header.h** to your project and `#import` the objective-c frameworks' header file there.

Please try this and do update here about result.

Comment: Ok.Got your point ! It should work.But it's not working ..no compile time errors ... just at run time some delegates are not firing.. so is it have anything to do with Header/Library/Framework search paths in Xcode build settings ? I am still wondering why ?

Comment: Make sure bridging header is set properly - http://www.learnswiftonline.com/getting-started/adding-swift-bridging-header/

Comment: The bridging header has been set correctly...as we're adding the PODS as dynamic framework.I guess bridging header its is not necessary

Comment: Yes, bridging header should not be necessary but still there are few pods out there who still require bridging header even if you integrate them using dynamic frameworks.

Answer (score 2):

Based on @MujtabaFR's answer and Microsoft's [plugin](https://github.com/microsoft/cocoapods-pod-linkage) source code, I found a workaround to **avoid** usage of `use_frameworks!` that is helpful for React Native.

---

In my case, I had a React Native project and a third party XCFramework. The framework I converted to a pod with a vendored xcframework. But next I got `No such module` error. The error is fixable via `use_frameworks!` option which I prefered to avoid.

Also, even if you converted pod to a framework, you can have a crash because of missed dynamic library file. It happens when the framework isn't listed in `[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks` build phase, i.e. the framework isn't embedded into your app.

---

To fix these issues, add to your Podfile the following code:

```
pre_install do |installer|
  installer.pod_targets.each do |pod|
    if pod.name == 'SQLCipher'
      def pod.build_type;
        Pod::BuildType.new(:linkage => :dynamic, :packaging => :framework)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

`SQLCipher` above is the name of a pod which I want to use as a framework. In my case, the vendored framework imports this library.

As a result, I get a target in `Pods` project which is configured as a framework. And other targets stay static.

Furthermore, such a pod is included in `[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks` build phase (see `Pods-YourProject-frameworks.sh` and `Pods-YourProject-frameworks-Debug-input-files.xcfilelist`). That means this framework could be linked dinamically.

[image: pod target as a framework]

*I use CocoaPods 1.11.3*

Answer (score 1):

From the answer of @MujtabaFR , i had errors says file not found in my pod global import header file and i can't resolve those. So in already working static libraries i tried inserting my dynamic framework, so i tried his solution with backward compatibility and so reversing his solution works fine for me, here it is for reference

```
dynamic_frameworks = ['aaa','bbb'] # <- swift libraries names

# Make all the other frameworks into dynamic frameworks by overriding the dynamic_framework? function to return true
pre_install do |installer|
  installer.pod_targets.each do |pod|
    if dynamic_frameworks.include?(pod.name)
      puts "Overriding the dynamic_framework? method for #{pod.name}"
      def pod.dynamic_framework?;
        true
      end
      def pod.build_type;
        Pod::BuildType.dynamic_framework
      end
    end
  end
end
```

So this remains my existing code as it is and inserted my new swift pod as dynamic framework.

Thank you @MujtabaFR

Answer (score 0):

```
pre_install do |installer|
    Pod::Installer::Xcode::TargetValidator.send(:define_method, :verify_no_static_framework_transitive_dependencies) {}
end
```

Add this in your podfile after use_frameworks!.

After deintegrate pod and install again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).