# Is there any way to use static and dynamic frameworks in single target in CocoaPods?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

When running the `install_dynamic_library` method (see definition in code block below), I want to use `use_frameworks! :linkage => :dynamic`. On the other hand, when running the `install_static_library` method, I want to use `use_frameworks! :linkage => :static`.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

plugin 'cocoapods-binary'
plugin 'cocoapods-pod-linkage'

def install_dynamic_library

  pod 'R.swift'
  pod 'Alamofire'
  pod 'Nuke'
  pod 'Parchment', '~> 3.0'
  pod 'SnapKit', '~> 5.0.0'
  pod 'Kanna', '~> 5.2.2'
  pod 'ImageViewer'
  pod 'PanModal'
  pod 'SideMenu'
  pod 'Toast-Swift', '~> 5.0.1'
  pod 'youtube-ios-player-helper', '~> 1.0.2'
  pod 'SwiftDate'
  pod "URLEmbeddedView"
  pod 'ActiveLabel'
end

def install_static_library

  pod 'GoogleMobileAdsMediationFacebook'
  pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics', '~> 8.1.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'FirebaseFirestore', :git => 'https://github.com/invertase/firestore-ios-sdk-frameworks.git', :tag => '8.1.0'
  pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift', '8.2.0-beta'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'
end

target :'MyApp' do
  install_dynamic_library
  install_static_library
end
```

Comment: This answer looks like it could help https://stackoverflow.com/a/60914505/179843

Comment: I was researching this and came across this useful article: https://medium.com/microsoft-mobile-engineering/mixing-static-and-dynamic-linking-in-cocoapods-83b6d4252c59